# How does Java's Matcher.group (int) method avoid match the contents of sub-braces inside parentheses

Tags: java, regex-group, matcher

I have a string like

```
String str = "美国临时申请No.62004615";
```

And a regex like

```
String regex = "(((美国|PCT|加拿大){0,1})([\\u4E00-\\u9FA5]{1,8})((NO.|NOS.){1})([\\d]{5,}))";
```

And other code is

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("1:"+matcher.group(1)+"\n"
                +"2:"+matcher.group(2)+"\n"
                +"3:"+matcher.group(3)+"\n"
                +"4:"+matcher.group(4)+"\n"
                +"5:"+matcher.group(5)+"\n"
                +"6:"+matcher.group(6)+"\n"
                +"7:"+matcher.group(7));
    }
```

I know Parenthesis () are used to enable grouping of regex phrases. And group 1 is the big group.

The second group is  ((美国|PCT|加拿大){0,1}) to match the "美国" or "PCT" or "加拿大".
The third group is ([\u4E00-\u9FA5]{1,8}) to match the chinese character which length is one to eight.
The fouth group is  ((NO.|NOS.){1}) to match the NO. or NOS.
The fifth group is  ([\d]{5,}) to match the number 
But the console is

```
1:美国临时申请No.62004615 2:美国 3:美国 4:临时申请 5:No. 6:No. 7:62004615
```

The group (2) is the same as group (3).The group (5) is the same as group (6)

It seems that group (3) rematches the sub-parentheses inside the parentheses again. I wonder if there is a way to match only the outermost parentheses。
The ideal result should be

```
1:美国临时申请No.62004615 2:美国  3:临时申请 4:No. 5:62004615
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a *non-capturing* group.  From [the Pattern documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum):

> `(?:`*X*`)`        *X*, as a non-capturing group

So, change this:

```
(美国|PCT|加拿大)
```

to this:

```
(?:美国|PCT|加拿大)
```

… and then it will not be represented as a group at all in the Matcher.

Some side notes:

- `{0,1}` is the same as writing `?`.
- `{1}` does nothing and can be removed entirely.
- `[\\d]` is the same as just `\\d`.